# how to set value in javascript in html input field using MaskedPassword.js

Tags: javascript, html, maskedpassword.js

We are using **MaskedPassword.js** in one of our input field as displayed below-

```
<input type="password" id="txttoPin" name="txttoPin" autocomplete="off" >
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            new MaskedPassword(document.getElementById("txttoPin"), '\u25CF');  
        </script>
```

But when we reloads the page we are setting some default value to this field using javascript as followed-

```
document.getElementById("txttoPin").value = "abcd";
```

Now **"abcd"** is getting displayed in plain format instead of masked format.
Can anyone help me out to resolved this issue.

Note: Please refer to https://www.sitepoint.com/better-passwords-1-the-masked-password-field/ for more details on MaskedPassword.js.

Comment: Could you provide the 'MaskedPassword.js' code that you describe?

Comment: @CallanHeard, please refer to my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks, have you read the article? It explicitly states that you cannot set a default value for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need several things to pull this off, based on the source code provided you need to:

1. Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded.
2. Save a reference of the `txttoPin` field and the `MaskedPassword` instance.
3. Get the new pin from the original `txttoPin` `_contextwrapper`.
4. Set the value from the new `pin`.
5. Use the `doPasswordMasking()` method from the `MaskedPassword` instance and pass the new `pin`.

---

**[SAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPnToxuR2OVVpmcxiErR?p=preview)**

```
// Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // This will be used as a template for the MaskedPassword class
  // to wrap it inside a span and add a hidden field inside the wrapper
  var oldPin = document.getElementById("txttoPin");
  // save MaskedPassword reference
  var masker = new MaskedPassword(oldPin, '\u25CF');  
  // get the new pin from the context wrapper
  var pin = oldPin._contextwrapper.lastChild;
  // set pin value
  pin.value = 'abcd';
  // set fullmask flag to true
  masker.fullmask = true;
  // perform masking!
  masker.doPasswordMasking(pin);

});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks alot for the help -
I have used your code in onPageShow() event as below-
Replaed 

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {`

with 

`window.onpageshow=function() {`